# NSMutableArray Add Object Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

So I've been stuck on this all morning, I have a MutableArray, which has been initialized, but when ever i try and add an element which has a value(I logged it and checked) the array remains null.

```
arr3=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(n==3)
    {
        [arr3 addObject:name];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@", arr3);
```

This always gives me a value which is empty. Does anyone know the error here?

Comment: plz show me value of name

Comment: Does `n` actually equal `3`? And why do you ignore the result of the call to `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`?

Comment: did u try this...? [arr3 insertObject:name atIndex:i];

Comment: @Vijayyadav the value of name keeps changing, but its a string value!

Comment: @rmaddy I used that for something else, should've removed it.. Sorry!

Comment: @vanilucky No i haven't tried that.. Will do so!

Comment: raghav-1357 Ok try that

Comment: @vanilucky Not working...

Comment: what does it means if(n==3)?? can u elaborate it please

Comment: like string *name=@"vijay" plz show me string and also elaborate it if(n==3)??

Comment: NSMutableString *testStr = [@"test" mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *arrayA = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Then you add your string to the array:

[arrayA addObject:testStr];
NSLog(@"%@", arrayA);    // output: test

Comment: try this once ...let me know it works or not

Comment: remove the condition `n==3` and tell me if it's still empty. Only then come back.

Comment: @ThomasKilian The condition n==3 is just a temp condition, to check if the counter from another view controller is equal to three, so that isn't the issue here.

Comment: NSMutableArray *mutArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *name=@"vijay";
    [mutArray addObject:name];
    NSLog(@"mutArray is:%@",mutArray);

Comment: that s worked for me..chack this once to remove that condition if (n==3)

Comment: You have three completely unrelated variables!!! i, n and names - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: n is a counter, used somewhere else. names is a string value I'm trying to add.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible if this `'if'` statement is true to didn't add an object to your array. Only for test add `'else'` to your `'if'`:

```
    arr3 = [NSMutableArray new];
    if (n==3) {
        [arr3 addObject:name];
    } else {
        [arr3 addObject:@"n not equal to 3"];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", arr3);
```

in this example array always will have one object. If `'NSLog'` will print only object from else statement it means that your problem is only with `'n'` which newer is equal to `'3'`.

And declaration of `arr3` have to be `'strong'` e.g.:

in function scope it will be simply:

```
NSMutableArray *arr3;
```

..because if `arr3` somehow is `__weak` after invoking `[NSMutableArray new];` it will be `nil`.

But I can see that array is not `nil` because you say that:

> This always gives me a value which **is empty**. Does anyone know the
>   error here?

so

> is empty

means `0` object not `nil` right?

Comment: Hey Roher thanks for your reply! Firstly, I checked my if condition, it isn't that. Secondly, yes you are right, the value of the array isn't nil, the array just remains empty. Do you have any other idea as to what to try?

Comment: So you mean that  '(n==3)' is true? Very weird if array doesn't contains object from 'if' or 'else' statement in NSLog print.

Comment: Yup. N is always true.

Comment: So 'NSLog(@"%d", arr3.count);' always returns 0?

Comment: It returns this :    ( )

Comment: so its means thath 'name' have empty string. Please create 'NSLog("name: %@", name);' it probably returns only "name:".

Comment: Wait you were right! name gets reallocated, and that was my problem.. Thank you! @roher